# How to do columwise division in R with another column?

Tags: r

I have the following variable `pp`:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4)
b = c(45,4,3,2)
c = c(34,23,12,45)
pp = cbind(a,b,c)
```

And another variable `qq`:

```
qq  = c(100,200,330,444)
```

I want to divide the sum of each column in `pp` by the sum of `qq` such that the output answer is a vector:

```
answer = [0.009310987, 0.05027933,  0.1061453]
```

I am new to R and looking for the most optimal way to do this type of division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
colSums(pp) / sum(qq)
          a           b           c 
#0.009310987 0.050279330 0.106145251
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp <- colSums(pp)
tmp/sum(qq)
```

> ```
>           a           b           c 
> 0.009310987 0.050279330 0.106145251
> ```